# How to create mutiple thumbnails for multiple image in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i try to create multiple thumbnail for multiple image. but it create for one image only and try increase original image width and height and its not increasing

please correct my code

here my code....

### uploading multiple image

```
   <?php

   if(!$this->input->post('upload')){
     $this->create();
   }

   else{

   $data['banner_img1']    =$_FILES['files']['name'][0];
   $data['banner_img2']    =$_FILES['files']['name'][1];
   $data['banner_img3']    =$_FILES['files']['name'][2];

   $update_id=$this->uri->segment(3);

    /* Create the config for upload library */

   $config=array(
    'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
    'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
    'max_size' => '2000'
    );

  /* Load the upload library */

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config); 

    if($this->upload->do_multi_upload('files')){

    }else{
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
    $image_data=$this->upload->data();

     /* Create the config for image library */

     $config = array(
        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image' => $this->gallery_path.'/banner_thumbs',            
        'maintain_ratio' =>true,
        'width' => '1200',
        'height'=> '600'

    );

/* Load the image library */
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    if($this->image_lib->resize('files')){

       if(is_numeric($update_id)){

          $this->_update($update_id, $data);

        }else{
           $this->_insert($data);
        }
        }else{
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
```

?>

Comment: try this tutorial: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload